# how can I define a method for slider change in controller of a javaFX program?

Tags: slider, javafx-8, fxml

I want to create a method in a controller of a fxml file, I want this method acts when the slider is changing.
I have a fxml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Slider fx:id="mySlider" blockIncrement="0.1" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="32.0" majorTickUnit="0.5" max="1.0" minorTickCount="1" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" />
      <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="75.0" />
      <Label layoutX="43.0" layoutY="103.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and I want to have a controller like this

```
package paper.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class RootController 
{

    @FXML
    private Slider mySlider;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;


    mySlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        textFieldOfEp.setText(Double.toString(newValue.doubleValue())   );

    });


    });


}
```

I want reflect the changes of slider in the textField.
like this picture:
[image]

How can I do this through a controller?
I don't want to do this in a start method of main class.

my start methos is like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(mainApp.class.getResource("view/Root.fxml"));
        AnchorPane ap=loader.load();
        Scene scene=new Scene(ap);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

the proposed answer worked.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. That code *is* triggered when the slider changes.

Comment: @James_D , really you have a fxml file with a slider. Its fx:id="mySlider", so while you don't have any method to put that piece of code in that, it doesn't work. if you put that in a start method, it works. but in controller, you must put that in a method.

Comment: The code goes in the controller's `initialize()` method. Is that what you're asking?\

Comment: @James_D, it produces exception. this method is running always. but I want to implement an event handler.

Comment: You *have* implemented an event handler. The code snippet you posted is an event handler. This is why it's not clear what you are asking. If you are getting an exception, then you need to [edit] your question, show the context for your code (i.e. the class and method in which it is placed), post the complete stack trace and identify which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: @James_D, you are right, but see [this] (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Slidervaluepropertychangelistener.htm).

Comment: @James_D, this is a sample of that. but pay attention to the start method.

Comment: Sorry, what are you talking about? I thought you were asking where you put that code if you are using FXML and a controller. As I told you, you put it in the controller's `initialize()` method. That code sample doesn't use FXML, so I don't understand how it is relevant to your question.

Comment: @James_D: imagine that you have a fxml file that contains a slider. if you have a button you can easily define on action method for that in your fxml file and by defining a method with that name in controller, it will work when somebody clicks on that button. I want a method like that. but I want that method trigger while the slider changes.

Comment: Here's an idea. Instead of asking me to "imagine" an FXML file, actually post your code in the form of an [MCVE]. Create an FXML file with a slider, create the controller in the way I have told you several times, and create an application class that loads the FXML and displays it.

Comment: Read my second comment again: "The code goes in the controller's `initialize()` method. Is that what you're asking?" Why don't you actually try that? If you have tried it, and it doesn't work, post that in your question, instead of something that won't compile.

Comment: it wont work. initialize has no relation with triggering changes in slider.

Comment: You have also omitted the `fx:controller` attribute in your FXML file (though maybe you are setting the controller in code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should register the listener in the controller's `initialize()` method:

```
package paper.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class RootController 
{

    @FXML
    private Slider mySlider;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    public void initialize() {

        mySlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            textField.setText(Double.toString(newValue.intValue()));


        });

    }


}
```

and make sure you either specify the controller in the FXML file:

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:controller="paper.view.RootController" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

or set the controller on the `FXMLLoader` directly in code.

This will automatically update the text field when the `intValue()` of the slider's value changes:

[image: Slider value at zero]

[image: Slider value at one]

Comment: thank you, it works. but I am confused about this initialize method. is it always running and is waiting for a trigger?

Comment: What do you mean "it is always running"?  The `initialize()` method runs once, when the FXML file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I just accidentally found that property `onValueChange` does the trick, needing a `ChangeListener<Number>` signature for the handler (`Double` works too):

```
<Slider onValueChange="#doStuff"/>

@FXML
private void doStuff(ObservableValue<Number> ovn, Number before, Number after) {
    System.out.println(before+" "+after);
}
```